# Julia built in function for sum of array?

Tags: julia

In Julia are there no built in functions to sum an array of numbers?

```
x = rand(10)
sum(x) # or sum(x, 1)

ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Float64 are not callable
```

I mean I could write a for loop to sum it as follows,

```
sum = 0.0    
for i in 1:length(x)
    sum += x[i]
end
```

but it just surprises me if julia don't have this built in somewhere?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As [@Michael K. Borregaard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2540037/michael-k-borregaard) mentions, you reasigned the variable `sum` (exported by default from `Base`) with the value of a `Float64` at some point. When you restated your session, `sum` was again the `Base.sum` default, ie:

```rb
julia> x = rand(10)         
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.661477                   
 0.275701                   
 0.799444                   
 0.997623                   
 0.731693                   
 0.557694                   
 0.833434                   
 0.90498                    
 0.589537                   
 0.382349        

julia> sum                                                    
sum (generic function with 16 methods)                        

julia> sum(x)               
6.733930084133119 

julia> @which sum(x)                                          
sum(a) in Base at reduce.jl:359
```

Notice the warning:

```rb
julia> original_sum = sum
sum (generic function with 16 methods)

julia> sum = x[1]                                             
WARNING: imported binding for sum overwritten in module Main  
0.6614772171381087                                                

julia> sum(x)                                                 
ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Float64 are not callable  

julia> sum = original_sum
sum (generic function with 16 methods)

julia> sum(x)               
6.733930084133119
```

Answer (score -4):

ok for whatever reason I re-started julia and sum() just worked, and I am incapable of producing the same bug. I suspect it has to do with some kind of memory issue since I have been storing massive DataFrames without freeing the memory, but really I don't know what's going on.

Comment: You probably used sum as a variable in your session, e.g. `sum = 10.` That's what the error message is telling you.